# Tires and warranty

Tags: tires

I have a 2015 BMW 328i MSPORT.  Back tires from manufacturer is 255/40 18. Can I put 265/35 on the same rims without voiding the warranty? thanks

terry

Comment: We need the wheel as well as the tyre dimensions to be able to help.

Comment: You would need to ask BMW about the warranty. We don't know what they will accept or not.

Answer (score 2):

*(YMMV. I'm not a laywer.)*

See also

[Does Changing Tires Void the Warranty for a new car?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/13064/does-changing-tires-void-warranty-for-a-new-car)

Which warranty?

If you're talking about the car warranty (bumper-to-bumper, powertrain or whatever): **In the USA, it is illegal for them (in this case, BMW or whichever company administers your warranty) to void the warranty on any part of the car due to modifications to unrelated parts of the car**.

This means that changing tires shouldn't have any warranty implications on anything other than the tires and, at most, the rims.

If you're talking about the *tire* warranty: you'd have to ask the tire vendor and/or manufacturer.

See [the Magnuson-Moss Warranty act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnuson%E2%80%93Moss_Warranty_Act) for more information on what they can and can't do regarding the warranty.

That said, I've heard of other franchies (specifically Hyundai) *attempting* to void a warranty due to rim and tire changes, but they're not really allowed to do that under US law. This extends to things like attempting to void the powertrain warranty because the owner installed an aftermarket exhaust or brakes.

They would have to prove that the modification was the source of the problem. On an engine failure, this can be difficult. For rims - well, unless they're 8" rims and the engine is running at 12000 RPM to go 40MPH, then you should be fine.

Comment: Very good answer! +1